When I make a new Geojson file by geojson.io, do I need to fit to the exact the border of each region?
I am making a geojson file of Berlin by myself. I am using geojson.io because it is very easy to use.
When I draw the poligon, if the line is out of border of Berlin, is there any problem? I think writing polygon lines exact on the border is very difficult. Is it enough to enclose the realm?
enter image description here
I draw this polygon and I received this geojson file. Some parts are out of Berlin, but it is very difficult to draw the exact same lines as their borders.
https://geojson.io/#new&map=6.13/52.847/11.81
"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "coordinates": [ [ [ 14.209192477308449, 53.94914887278037 ], [ 13.796399968595807, 53.674609722193 ], [ 13.318940153794046, 53.32700119774185 ], [ 12.800280031960597, 53.3777202848475 ], [ 10.91942990834184, 53.172617430609364 ], [ 11.516651130469455, 52.88487974998981 ], [ 11.799503507626781, 52.62204682189227 ], [ 12.029867932925953, 52.02381980594481 ], [ 12.676817695770694, 51.92761931278466 ], [ 12.958327808762306, 51.51597218908688 ], [ 13.992298402455475, 51.19488529569122 ], [ 15.098685232734113, 51.55418580198088 ], [ 14.844680361219275, 51.872953991367865 ], [ 14.794421974034378, 52.221082142351094 ], [ 14.845400232208135, 52.55346623540177 ], [ 14.256080178817143, 52.8679924906194 ], [ 14.488289240117638, 53.22560073593121 ], [ 14.209192477308449, 53.94914887278037 ] ] ], "type": "Polygon" } } ] }

The program reading your GeoJSON will not know you meant Berlin.  It will read in the polygon you actually specified.  Whether this is close enough depends on what the JSON is being used for.
